# JsonReadException in place of an ad

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, advertising

First time I ever saw an exception on StackExchange site.
It appears constantly on [this page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116/how-much-russian-do-i-need-to-know-for-travelling-within-russia) on both Chrome and Safari on Mac.

**Update (after 27 minutes):**

I'm unable to reproduce the issue on that page now.

**Stacktrace:**

```
 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue(Char currentChar)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader)
   at StackOverflow.Views.Ads.AdModel.ProcessQuestions(StringBuilder sb, String json, Int32 chance) in c:\Builds\StackExchange-Network\prod\source\StackOverflow\Views\Ads\AdModel.Render.cs:line 67
   at StackOverflow.Views.Ads.AdModel.get_MetaHouseAd() in c:\Builds\StackExchange-Network\prod\source\StackOverflow\Views\Ads\AdModel.Render.cs:line 41
   at ASP._Page_Views_Ads_DynamicHeightAds_cshtml.Execute() in c:\sites\stackexchange-network\Views\Ads\DynamicHeightAds.cshtml:line 9
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at StackOverflow.Controllers.StackOverflowController.RenderPartialRazorViewToString(Controller controller, String viewName, Object model) in c:\Builds\StackExchange-Network\prod\source\StackOverflow\Controllers\ControllerBase.cs:line 867
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

On a side note, `StackOverflowController` is sexy.

Comment: @slhck: For me, visiting the linked page always triggers the exception.

Comment: I see the same thing with Safari 5.1 and Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: I saw this about 5 hours ago, on either Travel or Home Improvement,  but not that particular page.

Comment: I see you haven't changed 'StackOverflow' to 'StackExchange' in your code yet :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some bad settings ended up on a few of our API servers, leading to some internal requests failing against a small subset of sites.

This manifested as broken ads.  It's been fixed, hopefully anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine on my side

http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/738184-731201120346am.png

(I do not think it depends on browser)

Comment: It looks fine to me now as well.